# WhatsApp Business API send image to customer as first message

Tags: whatsapp

As far as I know, to use the WhatsApp Business API one must use the APIs developed by WhatsApp regional partners

Looking at our a regional partner API, one cannot send an image to the customer as for the first message of the conversation

Is this a WhatsApp Business API restriction or is can be the partner API restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now this is a restriction by WhatsApp Business API. You can only use Message Templates as your first message which do not support images at the moment. You can read more about the API here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages#cutoffcontrol

Comment: Is it still valid ? In Header section whatsapp allow media first message but it will be static.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/message-templates/media-message-templates/